# How to save output of FINDSTR from C# to a text file?

Tags: c#, cmd, findstr

I am trying to run the findstr command from C# (Windows Forms).

I have tried this normally in Command Prompt it works fine.

```
string CD = @"P:\FIles";
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("findstr.exe");
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-M -S" + " " + quote + txtSearch.Text + quote + " " + quote+"dummy.txt"+quote + " > " + "C:\\Temp\\results.txt" ;
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = CD;
p.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = true;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

p.Start();

p.WaitForExit();
```

I would like to save the output to another text file with a specific location.

It would be even better if I could somehow return the result directly back to the form it self and maybe copy each line to a list box.

Comment: Why not just use C# to do what findstr does? Directory.GetFiles() will list files in subdirectories, File.ReadAllText() will provide the text for you to then examine.

Comment: @AlexK. I  have thousands of folders/sub folders and files to search. It took forever to search. Also the GetFiles method, the search option only allowed either All Directories or top level. I assume it took forever because of the amount of sub folders I had. I was trying to find a way so it only searched the sub directory of the given folder path. This FINDSTR command halved the search time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the output of a console application with reading the "StandardOutput" stream. But you have to set the StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput property to "true" before.

In your case:

```
    string CD = @"P:\FIles";
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("findstr.exe");
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-M -S" + " " + quote + txtSearch.Text + quote + " " + quote+"dummy.txt"+quote + " > " + "C:\\Temp\\results.txt" ;
    p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = CD;
    p.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = true;
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

    p.Start();

    p.WaitForExit();

    string sTest = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did try this read to end before but it just didnt work.

Comment: You mean now it works, but didn't work before? What was/is the problem?

Comment: I think I had the standard output.ReadToEnd after the p.Start()